# How do I install DoctrineMongoODMBundle on a Mac

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phar

I get this:

```
 Problem 1
 - doctrine/mongodb dev-master requires ext-mongo * -> no matching package found.
 - doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master.
 - doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb dev-master.
 - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module dev-master.
```

I have mongo and it's php extension installed on my Mac, but still no joy.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh my God I'm an idiot.  I didn't actually load mongo in php.ini.  I am ashamed.